# MPU6050 (ACCEL_YOUT_H , ACCEL_YOUT_L) register , have constant value

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope

every one
I have problem with reading data of (ACCEL_YOUT_H , ACCEL_YOUT_L) registers , I wanted to stabilize quadcopter with this sensor , I already read data from these register correctly with stm32f103 until a problem occurred , this problem was an -Instability- in the system , since then these registers have a constant value  , while all another data register have correct value and change .

with this condition my question is that : can I fix this problem in software with change configuration or reset sensor and how can do this , or my hardware damaged I must change sensor and use another one .

this is my module config :

```
Single_WriteI2C(0xD2,PWR_MGMT_1  , 0x08);disable temp sensor and enable 8mhz internal crystal[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Single_WriteI2C(0xD2,MPU_CONFIG  , 0x04);   //21HZ accelerometer bandwidth and 20HZ gyro bandwidth digital filter, input signal is off 
Single_WriteI2C(0xD2,SMPLRT_DIV  , 0x04); //1khz/5= 200hz---digital low pass filter is on
Single_WriteI2C(0xD2,GYRO_CONFIG , 0x18); //set on +-2000 degree/sec
Single_WriteI2C(0xD2,ACCEL_CONFIG, 0x08); // set on +-4 g/s
```

Answer (score 0):

about this problem , I change my mpu6050 sensor , and I see that all thing is ok , and this problem is occurred because of , a small mpu6050 hardware failure .
soo we can result that , a distortion in supply can make this kind of hardware problem in mpu6050 .
Of course, the fact that the product is Chinese is not ineffective. :|

Comment: This seems... dubious, but if you feel it has solved your problem, then please "accept" your self answer once the lockout time expires, so the question shows as resolved.  Your question itself never really had detail to be answerable.